# Is it possible to change Google sheet sidebar heading background color?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I want to change Google sheet sidebar heading background color. Have any idea to change background color using app script or any manual setting. Please help.
[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: Try changing the spreadsheet theme

Comment: thanks for your comments. but not working...

Answer (score 4):

This is probably impossible. The title bar is outside of the iFrame. If there was a way to set this it would be documented in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output like the .setTitle() method. However, I see no methods to help in this situation. The best you can get is a titleless bar.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with this code :

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Comment: Your code just sets the title, not the heading background color which was the actual question.